# Why does my attempt at detecting static members using SFINAE appear not to work?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I've just made a template to detect if a data member of a class is static defined or not. The accessibility of the member isn't what it should be concerned about(Assuming the member is always accessible by the template) in this post. Here is the code with any symbols for testing:

```
#include <conio.h>
//#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

struct A1
{
    int a;
};

struct A2
{
    static int a;
};

int A2::a{};

template < class My_Type >
struct TestStatic
{
    template < typename raw_ty > static char fTest(...);

    template < typename class_ty, typename arg_ty = decltype(class_ty::a) >
    static int fTest(int, arg_ty & = class_ty::a);

    enum nRes { result = sizeof(fTest<My_Type>(0)) - 1 };
};

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    i = TestStatic<A1>::result;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    i = TestStatic<A2>::result;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    _getch();
    return(0);
}
```

The question is when it was built with g++ 4.8 the compiling passed but got the result as two '3's rather than one '0' and another '3'. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Your template parameter names are rather confusing, aren't they?

Comment: It's just a draft. So it doesn't matter what name it should be because finally it won't be used anyway.

Comment: @unituniverse: It matters if you want to make life easier for people you're asking for help :)

Comment: okay thanks both of you and with apologize, I should have noticed that.

Comment: Note `_T` cannot be used as an identifier, it is reserved by the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is fundamentally flawed, because `decltype(T::x)` [is perfectly valid for non-`static` members](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/429f8f4ed5a6474d):

```
#include <iostream>

struct T
{
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(decltype(T::x)) << '\n';
}

// Output: 4
```

You can [get what you want](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2910f0472c983bb2) with [`std::is_member_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_pointer):

> If `T` is pointer to non-static member object or a pointer to non-static member function, provides the member constant value equal `true`. For any other type, value is `false`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct T
{
    int x;
};

struct S
{
    static int x;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << !std::is_member_pointer<decltype(&T::x)>::value << ' ';
    std::cout << !std::is_member_pointer<decltype(&S::x)>::value << '\n';
}

// Output: 0 1
```

This works because access to members through the `::` syntax results in a pointer-to-member only if the member is not-`static`; it is of course a normal variable access when the member is `static`.

Comment: I've just noticed yet, thanks. Is there any solution to make that works?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. Adding to answer.

Comment: I'm investigating this and found that the result may be mislead by overloaded operator & if the 'x' is class typed and if:

`struct Mislead
{
 int T::* operator & (void);
};

struct S
{
 static Mislead x;
};
`

Comment: `std::addressof` doesn't appear to be a viable fix for that here, unfortunately. And `std::offsetof` is simply undefined for static members. You may have to live with it. Why do you even need this, anyway?

Comment: I know it looks stupid but it may still possible to happen. and BTW is it possible to paste code right at here and why can't I input breaklines, You may noticed about the notifies and it's not just bothering you but also me either.

Comment: Comments aren't designed for codedumps really. As for the "notifies" I didn't understand you, sorry.

Comment: I mean the 'Inbox Messages' on the left-top of the web page.

Comment: Never mind. I thought you may receive many IMs since I have edited my post several times.